# No value for arguement in function call

Tags: python-3.x, dagster

I am very new to Python and am working through the [Dagster hello tutorial](https://dagster.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sections/learn/tutorial/hello_cereal.html)

I have set up the following from the tutorial

```
import csv

from dagster import execute_pipeline, execute_solid, pipeline, solid


@solid
def hello_cereal(context):
    # Assuming the dataset is in the same directory as this file
    dataset_path = 'cereal.csv'
    with open(dataset_path, 'r') as fd:
        # Read the rows in using the standard csv library
        cereals = [row for row in csv.DictReader(fd)]

    context.log.info(
        'Found {n_cereals} cereals'.format(n_cereals=len(cereals))
    )

    return cereals


@pipeline
def hello_cereal_pipeline():
    hello_cereal()
```

However pylint shows

> a no value for parameter

message.

What have I missed?

When I try to execute the pipeline I get the following

> D:\python\dag>dagster pipeline execute -f hello_cereal.py -n
>   hello_cereal_pipeline 2019-11-25 14:47:09 - dagster - DEBUG -
>   hello_cereal_pipeline - 96c575ae-0b7d-49cb-abf4-ce998865ebb3 -
>   PIPELINE_START - Started execution of pipeline
>   "hello_cereal_pipeline". 2019-11-25 14:47:09 - dagster - DEBUG -
>   hello_cereal_pipeline - 96c575ae-0b7d-49cb-abf4-ce998865ebb3 -
>   ENGINE_EVENT - Executing steps in process (pid: 11684) 
>   event_specific_data = {"metadata_entries": [["pid", null, ["11684"]],
>   ["step_keys", null, ["{'hello_cereal.compute'}"]]]} 2019-11-25
>   14:47:09 - dagster - DEBUG - hello_cereal_pipeline -
>   96c575ae-0b7d-49cb-abf4-ce998865ebb3 - STEP_START - Started execution
>   of step "hello_cereal.compute".
>                  solid = "hello_cereal"
>       solid_definition = "hello_cereal"
>               step_key = "hello_cereal.compute" 2019-11-25 14:47:10 - dagster - ERROR - hello_cereal_pipeline -
>   96c575ae-0b7d-49cb-abf4-ce998865ebb3 - STEP_FAILURE - Execution of
>   step "hello_cereal.compute" failed.
>               cls_name = "FileNotFoundError"
>                  solid = "hello_cereal"
>       solid_definition = "hello_cereal"
>               step_key = "hello_cereal.compute"
>
> File
>   "c:\users\kirst\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\errors.py",
>   line 114, in user_code_error_boundary
>       yield   File "c:\users\kirst\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\engine\engine_inprocess.py",
>   line 621, in _user_event_sequence_for_step_compute_fn
>       for event in gen:   File "c:\users\kirst\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\execution\plan\compute.py",
>   line 75, in _execute_core_compute
>       for step_output in _yield_compute_results(compute_context, inputs, compute_fn):   File
>   "c:\users\kirst\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\execution\plan\compute.py",
>   line 52, in _yield_compute_results
>       for event in user_event_sequence:   File "c:\users\kirst\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\dagster\core\definitions\decorators.py",
>   line 418, in compute
>       result = fn(context, **kwargs)   File "hello_cereal.py", line 10, in hello_cereal
>       with open(dataset_path, 'r') as fd:
>
> 2019-11-25 14:47:10 - dagster - DEBUG - hello_cereal_pipeline -
>   96c575ae-0b7d-49cb-abf4-ce998865ebb3 - ENGINE_EVENT - Finished steps
>   in process (pid: 11684) in 183ms  event_specific_data =
>   {"metadata_entries": [["pid", null, ["11684"]], ["step_keys", null,
>   ["{'hello_cereal.compute'}"]]]} 2019-11-25 14:47:10 - dagster - ERROR
>   - hello_cereal_pipeline - 96c575ae-0b7d-49cb-abf4-ce998865ebb3 - PIPELINE_FAILURE - Execution of pipeline "hello_cereal_pipeline"
>   failed.

[Update]
From Rahul's comment I realised I had not copied the whole example.
When I corrected that I got a FileNotFoundError

Comment: Did you run this example? https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/blob/83875982bd77675db19bb49ec49787a7bd260405/examples/dagster_examples/intro_tutorial/hello_cereal.py

Comment: From the code I see that there is a `open()` call to a file named `cereal.csv`. Can you confirm a file named `cereal.csv` is there in the place you are running the code from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the original question about why you are receiving a "no value for parameter" pylint message -

This is because the pipeline function calls don't include any parameters in the constructors and the `@solid` functions have parameters defined.  This is intentional from dagster and can be ignored by adding the following line either at the beginning of the module, or to the right of the line with the pylint message.  Note that putting the python comment below at the beginning of the module tells pylint to ignore any instance of the warning in the module, whereas putting the comment in-line tells pylint to ignore only that instance of the warning.

```py
# pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
```

Lastly, you could also put a similar ignore statement in a .pylintrc file too, but I'd advise against that as that would be project-global and you could miss true issues.

hope this helps a bit!

Comment: So the line could look like this: `    hello_cereal()  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter`

Answer (score 2):

Please check whether the dataset(csv file) which you are using is in the same directory with your code file. That may be the case why are you getting the

> FileNotFoundError error